# Giving read access to www-data user

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I want to give read and right access to `www-data` user..

When I Right click the folder `/var/www/` I selected the option Read and Write Files, but after clicking apply, it becomes `-` (dash) again..

I am creating new directory using php `exec` command. But because of this problem, the new folder is not being listed using the `ls` command.

What is the problem?

Comment: This is the third question you asked on this topic. First was moved, in the second you were informed that this is not the right site to ask this type of question, yet you post a third one. Please ask on the correct site. That is http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was because I was using `exec` instead of `shell_exec`. For the past two days I have been scratching my head, always the solution is a simple one.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to change permissions manually (from the console)?
You can do it like this: # chown -R www-data /var/www

This will change ownership of all files inside /var/www to www-data.